# Custom Button class over android Button in Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to make my own custom Button class in android, which handles all the android Button operations like creation, addition to layout and click. I achieved creation and addition to layout but i am not sure how to add the click event from my wrapper class. Below is the code snippet till what i achieved.

```
public class MyButton
{
    private string vText = "MyButton";
    private Activity vActivityContainer;

    private Button vButton;

    public MyButton(Object pContainer)
    {
        vActivityContainer = (Activity)pContainer;
    }

    public void addButton(Object pViewGroup)
    {
        vButton = (Button)createButton();
        Android.Views.ViewGroup layout = (Android.Views.ViewGroup)pViewGroup;
        layout.AddView(vButton);
    }

    private Object createButton()
    {

        Button button = new Button(vActivityContainer);
        setButtonProperties(button);
        return button;
    }

    private void setButtonProperties(Object pButtonObj)
    {
        Button b = (Button)pButtonObj;
        b.Text = vText;
    }


    public void setText(String pText)
    {
        this.vText = pText;
    }
}
```

Now when i make the instance of MyButton class, I am able to create an android button dynamically to my layout. Below is the code.

```
MyButton myb = new MyButton(Activity);
myb.setText("Tap Me");
myb.addButton(layout);
```

From the above way, I created a wrapper class for the button creation of Android.
Now I want to attach a click listener for all the buttons i create through my wrapper class. But i am not sure how to achieve that. In short to achieve something like below.

```
myb.MyClick += (sender, e) => {
// Click operations
}
```

Please guide me the correct way of doing that as i am new to C#. Feel free to ask, if the query is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement **IOnClickListener** of the button . There are two ways .

**Option 1**

You could directly implement the Interface in the Activity

```
public class xxxActivity :Activity,View.IOnClickListener
```

```
myb.SetOnClickListener(this);

public void OnClick(View v)
        {
           //...
        }
```

**Option 2**

You could define a class and implement the Interface

```
public class OnButtonClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        Button CurrentButton;
        public OnButtonClickListener(Button button)
        {
            CurrentButton = button;
        }

        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
           //...
        }
    }
```

```
myb.SetOnClickListener(new OnButtonClickListener(myb));
```

Comment: In Option2, How will i manage the body implementation of onClick in my activity class. By the approach it looks like, the implementation needs to be written inside OnButtonClickListener class. For, eg i need to call xyz() function on click of button from my activity class. How will i do that?

Comment: If so , you could use option 1